# How to keep track of a position no matter what screen size is?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a widget that selects an area in the page using JavaScript but the issue is that when it saves the `X/Y` and `Width/Height`, it's actually only relevant to that screen size, so if we try to draw that selection on another user's computer, it'll go off the correct position.

On what to rely and how to keep track of an `x` and `y` position no matter what the user's screen size is?

Comment: might be using css "position:fixed;"?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. How does screen size impact a pixel-based coordinate system?

Comment: It does, because websites are mostly centered, and the pixel coordinates are counted from left/top, so big screens will have much wider white space in the left, just think about it.

Comment: Dude the math would be the same, think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`obj.offsetLeft` and `obj.offsetTop` will always be relative to the top/left corner which is 0,0.

- Center x = `window.innerWidth / 2;`
- Center y = `window.innerHeight / 2;`
- Object width = `elementNode.offsetWidth;`
- Object height = `elementNode.offsetHeight;`

Position the object in the middle of the screen:

```
el = document.getElementById('my_div');
el.style.position = 'absolute';
el.style.left = Math.floor((window.innerWidth / 2) - (el.offsetWidth / 2)) + 'px';
el.style.top  = Math.floor((window.innerHeight / 2) - (el.offsetHeight / 2)) + 'px';
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4aenr/